# Even maximums in Lisp

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, lisp

I am trying to find the even maximums from a list in Lisp.

```
(defun m(L)
    (cond
        ((numberp L) L)
        ((atom L) most-negative-fixnum)
        (T (apply #'max (mapcar #'m L)))
    )
)
```

This "m" works for the maximum of a list(of lists) and the next to find the even maximums:

```
(defun _list (L)
    (mapcan #'((lambda (v)
                (cond
                    ((= 0 (mod v 2)) (list v))
                    (t nil)
                )
               ) (m L)
               )
    L
    )
)
```

I get the error  `((LAMBDA (V) (COND ((= 0 (MOD V 2)) (LIST V)) (T NIL))) (M L)) should be a lambda expression`
And I can't figure out why. I played with the paranthesis a lot but still nothing. Can somebody give me some better ideas why this happens?

Comment: your code formatting and indenting looks 'wild'. You need to improve your code formatting and then it is easier to spot errors like too many parentheses.

Comment: It's very hard to format Lisp code